# What is o' in this context (is same as "'prime")?

Tags: inequality, algorithms, notation

For Local Outlier Factor allgorithm snippit (full details at http://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Publikationen/Papers/LOF.pdf) :

```
For any positive integer k, the k-distance of object p, denoted as
k-distance(p), is defined as the distance d(p,o) between p and an
object o ∈ D such that:

For any positive integer k, the k-distance of object p, denoted as
k-distance(p), is defined as the distance d(p,o) between p and an
object o ∈ D such that:
(i) for at least k objects o’∈D \ {p} it holds that
d(p,o’) ≤ d(p,o), and
(ii) for at most k-1 objects o’∈D \ {p} it holds that
d(p,o’) < d(p,o).
```

Is o’ same as "O Prime" ? And so is therefore in some way related to "o".
And so is somehow related to "object o ∈ D " ?

Is this the correct way to interpret o’ ? That is, it's somehow related to the "o" definition. Is there a generic meaning for what the prime of any variable means ?

Comment: Why do you think that the tags fit this question?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila I see tags have been updated. I've noted for future questions.